# Would a tag for 'grammar terms' help?

Tags: discussion

This question is motivated by [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248237/how-does-the-gerund-bear-carry#comment538876_248237):

> There should be a tag "grammar terms". The tags etymology and Latin are rather vague and do not characterize the problem of this post sufficiently. And I think the discussion of grammar terms - their sense and nonsense - should be a main topic.

Comment: What about the 'part-of-speech' tag?

Comment: @Mitch But ''part-of-speech' is just one term? I am referring to the entire set?

Comment: Do you mean 'parts-of-speech' then?

Comment: @Mitch But 'parts-of-speech' = lexical category, which is just a subset of grammar?

Comment: OK, how about 'grammar' then or 'grammar terms'?

Comment: @Mitch 'grammar terms' sounds great! It doesn't exist though.